# Is it possible to access the files in ubuntu 12.04 while in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, ubuntu, filesystems

I don't know if it is possible to access the files in ubuntu while in windows. 
The local disk of my ubuntu is not visible in MyComputer. I hope someone can help me with my problem because it's a big waste of time rebooting my pc just to access my files in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (and Linux in general) uses the ext4 (or, previously, ext3) file system by default.  Windows doesn't have native support to read these file systems.  Windows only acknowledges a select few file systems, which include FAT variants (FAT16, FAT32), NTFS, ReFS (Win8.1), and a few others.

Linux, on the other hand, can access most filesystems that are out there.  Which is why you can see your Windows files from Ubuntu.

There is a program called [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/), available on SourceForge, which allows read-only access to ext2/3/4 partitions.  I just learned about it (from comments on this answer!) and haven't used it yet.

One option, if you want files to have read-write access by both Windows and Linux, is to set up a specific partition using one of the Windows-recognised filesystems.  NTFS is a good choice.  You can then use this drive from either operating system.  An NTFS partition lacks some of the under-the-hood advantages of ext4, but your computer will probably never miss them :)

Comment: -1 Incorrect! You CAN access `ext` partitions form Windows.

Comment: @Tzar Natively?

Comment: -1 Because you forgot to mention Ext2Read.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I didn't forget, I just didn't know about it!  Thanks for mentioning it; I've added it to my answer.  I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: Naw, he didn't ask for a FS accessible from both OS, but for a way to mount Ubuntu's partitions on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to access files on your Ubuntu partition from within Windows.

You will have to download and install a free piece of code called **Ext2Read*, available [on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/). The description of this utility states (and I quote *verbatim*):

> Ext2Read is an explorer like utility to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It now supports LVM2 and EXT4 extents. It can be used to view and copy files and folders. It can recursively copy entire folders. It can also be used to view and copy disk and file.

Perhaps you might give it a try.

Comment: I've already tried it but the software not works, I think it's a deprecated version

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can either use some special application like [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) to browse your Ubuntu Ext partition or install Ex2/Ext3 drivers for Windows. Second solution is cleaner (in my opinion), because you can stick to your usual file browser with familiar interface and Ext2/Ext3 partitions will be presented exactly as any other (NTFS/FAT).

Here is the [link to Ext2/Ext3 driver for windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

You can access via SSH! There is another Windows Apps call **winscp**. 
With this, you able to view all files via GUI.

Comment: Did you read the question?